# jquery php json example

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

How do I populate several text input fields with corresponding data, executing php-mysql query script once only?
e.g.

```
<form name="video" action="mysql.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="videofrm">
                <p>
                    <label for="url">url/gallery:</label><input class="text" type="text" id="url" name="url"/>
                    <input id="favorite" class="text" type="checkbox" name="favorite" value="true"/>
                    <label for="favorite" class="noneFloat">favorite</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="thumb" type="file" name="thumb"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="title">title:</label><input class="text" type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="desc">description:</label><input class="text" type="text" id="desc" name="description"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="country">country:</label><input class="text" type="text" id="country" name="country"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="categories">categories:</label><input class="text" type="text" id="categories" name="category"/>
                </p>
                <input type="button" value="fetch" id="fetch"/>
                <input type="reset" value="clear"/>
            </form>
```

I need to populate input text fields with:

```
select url,title,desc,country,category
from video where url='something';
```

First I need to know how to write this kind of php script so it returns json datatype, and afterwards how to populate text input fields, using jquery, with returned data.

`many thanks

Comment: This needs a good deal of clarification in order to be answerable. Are you asking how to populate text inputs from database values?

Comment: what part is not clear to you? it says php-mysql query script, it is for sure not from my diary dude. of course it is a database in question.

Comment: Do you know any PHP or JavaScript? If not, reading some tutorials would be a good start. We will not just do your work for you...

Comment: You might want looking at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php.

Comment: @atno - I've boost you up a little bit :)

Comment: @Felix Kling: of course i know. i just need json part to be explained. many thanks

Comment: @daniel: Well, you didn't post any PHP or JavaScript code, so we cannot know...

Comment: @pimvdb: thanks, that is very valuable info

Comment: @Felinx: i didn't want to bother you guys with one pdo query, as well with one jquery ajax call. but i do know this thing, just need brief json part demonstration. leave out all event handlers ands stuff, just pure json manipulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and looks a bit like a "please write my code" request (although it wasn't necessarily one). Try to avoid that impression, and mention what you have already tried/researched to avoid downvoting.

Some pointers:

- Use [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) to get mySQL result data into JSON form on PHP side
- Send the [correct content-type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) to go with it: [`header("content-type: application/json");`](http://php.net/header)
- Use jQuery's [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) shorthand (or `.ajax()` with a `json` dataType) to fetch the script
- Populating the input fields with the data is trivial using `.val()`.

Comment: many thanks. that is all i needed, some quick direction. after all, we are all different and have our own ways of expressing ourselves. as we are writing apps to deal with this kind of sophisticated judging we shouldn't forget integrated it within our own mind.